Issue with Polars and Polars_talib
I'm fairly new to programming as a whole and I'm trying to learn using Polars with the polars_talib library.
However when I import polars_talib I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 8
      6 import mintalib as mt
      7 import pandas_ta as pta 
----> 8 from polars.utils.udfs import _get_shared_lib_location
      9 import polars_talib  as plt 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polars.utils'

And I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting this message.
I expected the library to import without error, tried Googling for a fix but couldn't find anything useful. I've reinstalled Polars with all optional dependencies and polars ta_lib, still nothing.

This issue has been fixed in the latest version of the library. Please update to version 0.1.3, which now supports Polars v1, to resolve the problem.

polars.utils were removed from the library in the latest versions of polars. So you need to downgrade to one of previous polars versions:
pip install --force-reinstall 'polars<=0.40'

However function _get_shared_lib_location starts from _ symbol. This usually means that function is not intended for public usage.
Also _get_shared_lib_location function has a deprecation message which says that it is recommended to switch to the polars.plugins.register_plugin_function instead.
